# Nested threads in C++ 11 multithread programming

Tags: multithreading, c++11

At first, I create four threads and each of them will call a GPU function. However, within each of the four, I also want to create two threads. One is to read data from the disk and the other is to do the computation. I am not sure if I can create a nested thread in C++. I think this is not a neat code. Can I have another way to solve the problem?

Comment: It doesn't matter which thread is creating a new thread. Threads of a process do not form a tree, there's no nesting, it''s all flat.

Comment: Re, "I think this is not a neat code," Well, so far, you are the only person who has seen it.  You aren't going to get any meaningful opinions about it if you don't show it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it should be no problem to create a new thread from a running thread.
Like you assume it's not the best solution, because creating/destroying threads often isn't cheap and the more threads you have the more context switches you have which is or can be also a performance penalty.

So you could create a thread pool which has given number of threads and let the thread pool threads work on reading data from disk and do computations. You would avoid massive creation and destroying of threads.

If you also create/destroy often the threads who are calling GPU functions you could create two threadpools one for the threads calling the GPU functions and one threadpool for reading from disk and computations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use std::async and do away with thread management entirely. Or use a hybrid approach where you have the 4 core threads which I assume will never die and then in those functions where you wish to perform more asynchronous work you can use std::async.

https://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/10/17/cpp-11-async-tutorial/

It's not clear whether async tasks are using thread pools. If you want to ensure high performance, which you probably care about since you're using GPUs, you should use a thread pool.

http://roar11.com/2016/01/a-platform-independent-thread-pool-using-c14/